# Connecting a Calendar with a Database

Tags: flutter

I am using the flutter package **table_calendar** and want to connect its events with a database.

For this use, I chose the **sqflite** package and **flutter_bloc**. There is a great tutorial on how to here: [Database Storage in Flutter using Sqflite](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E4yRzqChFxY)

The database uses a **List** datastructure but the calendar a **Map< DateTime, List< dynamic>>**.

I wrote a method that takes each event for a day found in the Database List and writes it in the Map in order to show everything in the UI. The regex are there since I save the date as a **Text** within the database and separate it with dots.

```
  void shiftListToCustomEventsMap(List<Shift> shiftList) {
    for (int i = 0; i < shiftList.length; i++) {
      Shift shift = shiftList[i];
      String helpStringForDate = shift.dateOfShiftString;
      RegExp exp = new RegExp(r'(\d+)');
      Iterable<RegExpMatch> matches = exp.allMatches(helpStringForDate);
      int date = int.parse(matches.elementAt(0).group(0));
      int month = int.parse(matches.elementAt(1).group(0));
      int year = int.parse(matches.elementAt(2).group(0));
      DateTime shiftDateTime = new DateTime.utc(year, month, date, 12);

      if (customEvents[shiftDateTime] == null) {
        // creating a new List and passing a widget
        customEvents[shiftDateTime] = [_buildShiftContainer(shift: shift)];
      } else {
        List<dynamic> helpList = customEvents[shiftDateTime];
        helpList.add(_buildShiftContainer(shift: shift));
      }
    }
  }
```

Thus, I am using two data structures to handle the data, which is sub-optimal.

The problems start when I want to delete an event from the calendar.

**Problem:**

If I delete the second event of a day with the use of an index, the event gets deleted within the **Map** as I would like to but in the **Database**, it takes the second entity overall and deletes it.

**Sub-Optimal Solution:**

A way to solve it would be to create for each date a new Table in the Database but I am not sure that this is the best way to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.

I now save the ID of the row found in the DB within my Shift object. I pass this object to a method to create a widget which I then use within a ListView.builder as a calendar event.

Now when trying to delete a calendar event, I retrieve the whole information of the widget. Within this widget, I have saved the ID position of the equivalent event within the database. Then I pass this id to delete the row from the database.

The following code is a part of the propose solution:

```
Shift deleteShift =
    getParametersFromWidgetInTheList(
        index: index);
// remove from database
DatabaseProvider.db
    .delete(deleteShift.id)
    .then((_) => BlocProvider.of<ShiftBloc>(
            context)
        .add(DeleteShift(deleteShift.id)));
// remove from customEvents Map
customEvents[_controller.selectedDay]
    .removeAt(index);
```